# SAP RFC call using java spring application

Tags: java, spring, sapjco3

ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException class is not getting while making RFC calls to SAP system through java spring web application.

SEVERE: Servlet /autobot threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException

Comment: put the jar in your classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `sapjco3.jar` file into the class path of your Web Application Server.

I do not recommend to put it into your web application archive (.ear/.war) itself, because the `sapjco3.jar` file can only be loaded once due to its dependency to native shared libraries which can only be loaded once. Otherwise, if putting it into your web application archive, the first invocation of your app will succeed but following loads of your app or of other apps, which also use the JCo, won't work. In this case the JCo initialization will fail because the native shared library `sapjco3.dll` / `libsapjco3.so` cannot be loaded twice.